# Dynamic Field Names

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is in ASP.NET with C#. A small snippet of that code looks like this:

```
case 1:
{
    txtQty1.Text = decQty.ToString("0.0"); 
    txtDesc1.Text = strDescription; 
    txtCost1.Text = decCost.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtVAT1.Text = decTax.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtTotal1.Text = decTotal.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtGrossEach1.Text = decGrossEach .ToString( "0.00");
    lblCostCodeProfileId1.Text = iCostCodeProfileId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    SetupCostCentre1(iCostCodeProfileId);
    // cost centres should be refreshed using the value of Cost Code Profile
    ddlCostCentres1.SelectedValue = iCostCentre.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if(iCostCentre !=0)
    {
        RefreshExpenseCodeList1(iCostCentre);
    }
    ddlCostCentres1.SelectedValue = iCostCentre.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    ddlExpCode1.SelectedValue = iExpenseCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ddlVatRate1.SelectedValue = iVatRate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break;
}
case 2: 
{
    txtQty2.Text = decQty.ToString("0.0"); 
    txtDesc2.Text = strDescription; 
    txtCost2.Text = decCost.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtVAT2.Text = decTax.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtTotal2.Text = decTotal.ToString("0.00"); 
    txtGrossEach2.Text = decGrossEach.ToString("0.00");
    lblCostCodeProfileId2.Text = iCostCodeProfileId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    SetupCostCentre2(iCostCodeProfileId);
    // cost centres should be refreshed using the value of Cost Code Profile
    ddlCostCentres2.SelectedValue = iCostCentre.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (iCostCentre != 0)
    {
        RefreshExpenseCodeList2(iCostCentre);
    }
    ddlCostCentres2.SelectedValue = iCostCentre.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    ddlExpCode2.SelectedValue = iExpenseCode.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ddlVatRate2.SelectedValue = iVatRate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break; 
}
```

Now, the only difference between Case 1 and Case 2 in the above list is in the names of the fields being filled. There is a lot of scope for omission or error here, where what is required is for each set to be treated exactly the same.

Is there any way I can dynamically refer to the fields and write the code only once.

Answer (score 2):

Textboxes are objects as anything else, so you can assign variables to them.

```
var txtQty = (param == 1) ? txtQty1 : txtQty2;

txtQty.Text = decQty.ToString("0.0");
```

However it seems that you should have one user control which will hold all you TextBoxes, and put it twice on the page. Put code from this `switch` to the user control as well.

Method inside user control:

```
public void FillControls(DataParams p) {

  txtQty.Text = p.decQty.ToString("0.0"); 
  txtDesc.Text = p.strDescription; 
  txtCost.Text = p.decCost.ToString("0.00"); 
  txtVAT.Text = p.decTax.ToString("0.00"); 
  txtTotal.Text = p.decTotal.ToString("0.00"); 
      ...
}
```

And in your page or parent control

```
 var uc = (param == 1) ? userControl1 : userControl2;

 uc.FillControls(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just pull the common code into a method that takes the controls as arguments.

```
private void SomeMethod( TextBox qty, TextBox desc, TextBox cost, TextBox, vat, etc... )
{
    qty.Text = decQty.ToString("0.0"); 
    desc.Text = strDescription; 
    cost.Text = decCost.ToString("0.00"); 
    vat.Text = decTax.ToString("0.00"); 
    total1.Text = decTotal.ToString("0.00"); 
    grossEach.Text = decGrossEach .ToString( "0.00");
    /// etc...
}
```

Then in your calling code:

```
case 1:
    SomeMethod( txtQty1, txtDesc1, txtCost1, etc... );
    break;

case 2:
    SomeMethod( txtQty2, txtDesc2, txtCost2, etc... );
    break;
```

Comment: This solution should be used if there is no way to refactor page to use user controls.

Comment: This solution was the most convenient for me to implement at this point. Using a Single User Control would have been better, but at this stage of development, it would involve backtracking too much. As it is, I have managed to remove loads of lines of unnecessary code, and reduced the likelihood or error. One thing that would definitely improve the above would be if I could dynamically name this fields, ie. Case a: SomeMethod( txtQty+a, txtDesc+a, txtCost+a, etc... );

Comment: You could use the Find() method of the Controls collection but in the end you would probably end up writing _more_ code and introducing a greater chance for bugs because you really should be checking to ensure you actually got a control and didn't just introduce a null reference exception. IMO, txtQty1 and txtQty2 aren't the greatest names anyway, it would be nice if they were more descriptive (e.g. txtQtyRetail and txtQtyWholesale). Obviously I'm just guessing at what 1 and 2 stand for, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Code reduction is a noble goal, but if you trade compile-time checking for run-time errors, or easy-to-read for hard-to-read, then the trade-off isn't work it IMO. Remember that some day someone besides you will be maintaining this code.